# Pandas Groupby with Aggregate, and Quantiles

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to `groupby` a `pandas` DataFrame and calculate quantiles and aggregates from a column.

Here's a sample DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'id': [1, 1, 1, 2],
                   'cat': ['p','p','p','n'],
                   'num': [5, 10, 10, 5],
                   'v': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'v2'],
                   'p': [1000, 1300, 1400, 1100]
                 })
```

I am looking for a solution that can scale with `n` # of categorical and numeric columns. For `numeric` and `categorical` columns, aggregate using `mode` function.

With `p`, create two new columns, range of `.25` and `.75` quantiles and `min` and `max`.

Expected output:

```
id  cat num  v    pquantile     min-max    

1   p   10   NaN  1075 - 1325   1000 - 1400  
2   n   5    v2   1100          1100
```

Also, aggregate function `mode` needs to be able to handle a tie.

Answer (score 1):

As outlined in your question, first group by "cat" and use the `agg` method to select the "most common value".

`df_grouped_by = df.groupby('cat').agg(pd.Series.mode)`

Then compute the `0.25` and `0.75` quantiles for each list value in the `p` column:

`df_grouped_by['pquantile'] = df_grouped_by.apply(lambda row : np.quantile(row['p'],[0.25,0.75]), axis = 1)`

Finally, compute the min and max values using a similar logic:

`df_grouped_by['min-max'] = df_grouped_by.apply(lambda row : [np.min(row['p']), np.max(row['p'])] , axis = 1)`

This yields:

```
cat id  num v   p                   pquantile           min-max                         
n   2   5   v2  1100                [1100.0, 1100.0]    [1100, 1100]
p   1   10  []  [1000, 1300, 1400]  [1150.0, 1350.0]    [1000, 1400]
```

You may then reindex as you see fit and drop the `p` column.